# Angular 2 : ngFor nesting issue

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am getting ngFor nesting issue where it shows 'Cannot read property 'Field' of undefined'.

I tried referring other questions but was not able to get it. please help how do i render data correctly

```js
// service call

this.xmldataService.getReport().subscribe(
      (report) => {
        this.group = report.CrystalReport.Group;
      });
      
      
// Error

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Field' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:23)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:12641)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12053)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12367)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12339)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12054)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12367)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12313)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12059)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13041)
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" *ngFor="let head of group; let i = index">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let d of head.GroupHeader.Section.Text; let i = index">{{d.TextValue}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let d of head.Details.Section.Field; let i = index">{{d.value}}</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

below is my json for which i get error

```js
{
 "@Level": "2",
 "Section": {
  "@SectionNumber": "0",
  "Field": [{
   "@Name": "GroupNameTEAMNO1",
   "@FieldName": "GroupName ({PDA112P.TEAM_NO})",
   "FormattedValue": "DL04",
   "Value": "DL04"
  }, {
   "@Name": "ASMPROCNO1",
   "@FieldName": "{PDA112P.ASM_PROC_NO}",
   "FormattedValue": "3H878",
   "Value": "3H878"
  }, {
   "@Name": "UNITNO1",
   "@FieldName": "{PDA112P.UNIT_NO}",
   "FormattedValue": "H83937",
   "Value": "H83937"
  }, {
   "@Name": "APPROVEDDATE1",
   "@FieldName": "{PDA112P.APPROVED_DATE}",
   "FormattedValue": null,
   "Value": null
  }, {
   "@Name": "REJECTEDDATE1",
   "@FieldName": "{PDA112P.REJECTED_DATE}",
   "FormattedValue": null,
   "Value": null
  }, {
   "@Name": "MAINTDATE1",
   "@FieldName": "{PDA112P.MAINT_DATE}",
   "FormattedValue": "04/20/2017",
   "Value": "04/20/2017"
  }, {
   "@Name": "RESNFORCHANGE1",
   "@FieldName": "{PDA112P.RESN_FOR_CHANGE}",
   "FormattedValue": "CHANGED GET TO GRASP IN WORKING POINT DETAIL NO PCF REQUIRED",
   "Value": "CHANGED GET TO GRASP IN WORKING POINT DETAIL NO PCF REQUIRED"
  }, {
   "@Name": "ISSUEDDATE1",
   "@FieldName": "{PDA112P.ISSUED_DATE}",
   "FormattedValue": null,
   "Value": null
  }]
 }
}
```

below is output for group tag

```js
{"@Level":"1","GroupHeader":{"Section":{"@SectionNumber":"0","Text":[{"@Name":"Text16","TextValue":"Team"},{"@Name":"Text17","TextValue":"Process"},{"@Name":"Text18","TextValue":"Unit"},{"@Name":"Text19","TextValue":"Maint.\n\nDate"},{"@Name":"Text21","TextValue":"Unit Rank /\n\nQuality Issues"},{"@Name":"Text20","TextValue":"Description of Change"},{"@Name":"Text22","TextValue":"Issued \n\nDate"},{"@Name":"Text24","TextValue":"Rejected\n\nDate"},{"@Name":"Text23","TextValue":"Approved\n\nDate"}]}},"Details":{"@Level":"2","Section":{"@SectionNumber":"0","Field":[{"@Name":"GroupNameTEAMNO1","@FieldName":"GroupName ({PDA112P.TEAM_NO})","FormattedValue":"DL04","Value":"DL04"},{"@Name":"ASMPROCNO1","@FieldName":"{PDA112P.ASM_PROC_NO}","FormattedValue":"3H878","Value":"3H878"},{"@Name":"UNITNO1","@FieldName":"{PDA112P.UNIT_NO}","FormattedValue":"H83937","Value":"H83937"},{"@Name":"APPROVEDDATE1","@FieldName":"{PDA112P.APPROVED_DATE}","FormattedValue":null,"Value":null},{"@Name":"REJECTEDDATE1","@FieldName":"{PDA112P.REJECTED_DATE}","FormattedValue":null,"Value":null},{"@Name":"MAINTDATE1","@FieldName":"{PDA112P.MAINT_DATE}","FormattedValue":"04/20/2017","Value":"04/20/2017"},{"@Name":"RESNFORCHANGE1","@FieldName":"{PDA112P.RESN_FOR_CHANGE}","FormattedValue":"CHANGED GET TO GRASP IN WORKING POINT DETAIL NO PCF REQUIRED","Value":"CHANGED GET TO GRASP IN WORKING POINT DETAIL NO PCF REQUIRED"},{"@Name":"ISSUEDDATE1","@FieldName":"{PDA112P.ISSUED_DATE}","FormattedValue":null,"Value":null}]}}}
```

Comment: Can you give more detail of your data structure/model? e.g. group? head?

Comment: added json for your reference

Comment: And what about output of console.log(this.group) if you put in "service call". I mean if you added as:
this.xmldataService.getReport().subscribe(
      (report) => {
        this.group = report.CrystalReport.Group;
        console.log(this.group);
      });

Comment: added console result of this.group

Comment: Is that the data you expect to retrieve? Normally, I would see data from console.log window as object data. How did you get that json data from? Was it from console.log window or you query directly from database? Another thing is how did you declare your object variable such as group?

Comment: With one condition that everything seem to be okay from your code, one thing you can try is using *ngIf="group" to make sure that you get the data available before rendering to view

Comment: as you had no error issue from the first *ngFor="let d of head.GroupHeader.Section.Text; let i = index" but the second *ngFor="let d of head.Details.Section.Field; let i = index" and I have checked your data and it seems to be okay. I suspect that there might be a namespace collision in your local variable d. Can you try to name them differently as d1 and d2 respectively?

Comment: Also, if you are getting this JSON from a service take a look at the [Async Pipe](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-async-data-binding-with-ng-if-and-ng-else), i.e. `*ngFor='let d of head.Details.Section.Field | async'`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that problem is that not all items in 'group' collection have head.Details.Section field. I recommend you to log all your items to make sure that they have appropriate field.

Comment: i have added json for your reference

Answer (score 0):

Your 'value' is in lowercase in the template but uppercase in the json: 'Value'

After looking through your entire JSON, you are also missing the 'Section' property on several groups. See this fiddle that iterates over your entire JSON and outputs the 'Section' of each group: https://jsfiddle.net/j3eo4u7y/ (open console and hit run, look at logs)

```
j.CrystalReport.Group.map(g => g.Details).map(d => console.log(d.Section))
```

Comment: are you sure that's youre entire json? What does the upper level look like 'Details'?

Comment: json file is too huge so i have added it to this link https://jsonblob.com/a995ae6b-3589-11e7-ae4c-fff100ae78bd

Comment: I have revised my answer. I traversed your entire json and you are missing 'Section' in several Details objects, check the fiddle.

Comment: getting some undefined values... why so

Comment: because your object is missing 'Section' property in a lot of 'Details' objects